# How can I dynamically update a matrix containing f-string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I'm writing a console-based Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python, and I've got the definitions for the board and current placements of letters at the top:

```
board_dict = {'a1': ' ', 'b1': ' ', 'c1': ' ',
              'a2': ' ', 'b2': ' ', 'c2': ' ',
              'a3': ' ', 'b3': ' ', 'c3': ' '}

board = [[f'1:| {board_dict["a1"]} | ', f'{board_dict["b1"]} | ', f' {board_dict["c1"]}|'],
         [f'2:| {board_dict["a2"]} | ', f'{board_dict["b2"]} | ', f' {board_dict["c2"]}|'],
         [f'3:| {board_dict["a3"]} | ', f'{board_dict["b3"]} | ', f' {board_dict["c3"]}|']]

valid_choices = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']


def show_board():
    print('Showing board')
    print('  __A_|_B_|_C__')
    for row in board:
        print(row[0] + row[1] + row[2])
        print('  -------------')
```

When I redefine one of the items in `board_dict`, I expected the `board` matrix to respond accordingly, but it doesn't.

I did manage to achieve the functionality by redefining the whole matrix:

```
def show_board():
    global board
    board = [[f'1:| {board_dict["a1"]} | ', f'{board_dict["b1"]} | ', f' {board_dict["c1"]}|'],
             [f'2:| {board_dict["a2"]} | ', f'{board_dict["b2"]} | ', f' {board_dict["c2"]}|'],
             [f'3:| {board_dict["a3"]} | ', f'{board_dict["b3"]} | ', f' {board_dict["c3"]}|']]
    print('Showing board')
    print('  __A_|_B_|_C__')
    for row in board:
        print(row[0] + row[1] + row[2])
        print('  -------------')
```

But my question is this:
Is there a way to make this happen dynamically without redefining the entire matrix each time? Or is this the only way?

Comment: Not with `f` strings, no.  They are evaluated at the point they are encountered.  After that, they are just plain old strings.  However, you could use `string.format` for this; put place  holders in the `board` list and then specify the values in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with `string.format`:

```
board_dict = {'a1': ' ', 'b1': ' ', 'c1': ' ',
              'a2': ' ', 'b2': ' ', 'c2': ' ',
              'a3': ' ', 'b3': ' ', 'c3': ' '}

board = ['1:| {a1} | {b1} | {c1} |',
         '2:| {a2} | {b2} | {c2} |',
         '3:| {a3} | {b3} | {c3} |']

valid_choices = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']

def show_board():
    print('Showing board')
    print('  __A_|_B_|_C__')
    for row in board:
        print( row.format(**board_dict) )
        print('  -------------')

show_board()
```

Output:

```
Showing board
  __A_|_B_|_C__
1:|   |   |   |
  -------------
2:|   |   |   |
  -------------
3:|   |   |   |
  -------------
```

Or, even simpler:

```
board_dict = {'a1': ' ', 'b1': ' ', 'c1': ' ',
              'a2': ' ', 'b2': ' ', 'c2': ' ',
              'a3': ' ', 'b3': ' ', 'c3': ' '}

board = '\n'.join([
         '  __A_|_B_|_C__',
         '1:| {a1} | {b1} | {c1} |',
         '  -------------',
         '2:| {a2} | {b2} | {c2} |',
         '  -------------',
         '3:| {a3} | {b3} | {c3} |',
         '  -------------'])

valid_choices = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']

def show_board():
    print('Showing board')
    print( board.format(**board_dict) )

show_board()
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that unpacking method, or that it could be used in function calls! Marking this as the answer, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a render function that takes in a board?

```
import typing
import typing_extensions

SpaceValue = typing.Literal['X', 'O', ' ']

class Board(typing_extensions.TypedDict):
    a1: SpaceValue
    a2: SpaceValue
    a3: SpaceValue
    b1: SpaceValue
    b2: SpaceValue
    b3: SpaceValue
    c1: SpaceValue
    c2: SpaceValue
    c3: SpaceValue

game_board: Board = {
    'a1': ' ',
    'b1': ' ',
    'c1': ' ',
    'a2': ' ',
    'b2': ' ',
    'c2': ' ',
    'a3': ' ',
    'b3': ' ',
    'c3': ' '
}

def show_board(board: Board):
    row_length = 3
    rows = [list(board.values())[0:len(board)][i:i+row_length] for i in range(0, len(board), row_length)]
    print('Showing board')
    print('  __A_|_B_|_C__')
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        print(f"{i+1}:| " + " | ".join(row) + " |")
    print('  -------------')

show_board(board)
```

Results:

```
Showing board
  __A_|_B_|_C__
1:|   |   |   |
2:|   |   |   |
3:|   |   |   |
  -------------
```